# Why is it when i scan a QR code with QR Scanner app the QR produced looks different from the printed QR code?

Tags: qr-code

this is my 1st question here but i guess i'll keep it short.

I'm currently working on an app to scan QR codes and came across a code that cant be scanned.

After some testing, I found out that the QR scanner app (from playstore) works but the output looks different from the original printed QR code. May I know why?

Thanks for any tips :)

[Printed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Llss.jpg)

[Code detected by the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ukBM.jpg)

Comment: The content speaks of "LOT" and "EXP", indicating that the intention was to create a GS1 structured code. In that case, the code is not generated the right way, and the content is wrong.

Comment: Please add some example